# read keyboard input within a pipelined read loop

Tags: bash, unix, sh

In a script, I'd like to read a process output line by line, and get a confirmation from the user. So far I've done this:

```
mycommand-outputpiped | while (read line)
do
   read line
   #dostuff

   read confirm #oops -> this read the next item from the pipe, not the keyboard
done
```

So I tried to add:

```
read confirm < /dev/stdin
```

But it didn't change the thing, it still reads the next line from the pipe... 
How should I handle this?

Comment: Not related, but why do you have a `read` command in both the condition list and the loop body for the variable `line`?

Comment: I'm not sure about that - I believe the first checks there are still datas to read while the second reads the datas. I'm not sure how to clean it up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `read` commands are reading from the standard input stream inherited from the `while` loop. The following *should* work; your second read needs to read directly from the terminal, not `/dev/stdin` (which is the pipe).

```
mycommand-outputpiped | while read line
do
    # do stuff
    read confirm < /dev/tty
done
```

Note that there is just one `read`, in the `while` condition, and that it is *not* enclosed in parentheses (which would create a subshell, and `line` would only be available in that subshell, not the loop body).